# How to disable a system ribbon button in MS Dynamics CRM 2011 using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable System Ribbon in CRM 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942676/disable-system-ribbon-in-crm-2011)

Any one please explain how to disable the system ribbon button like 'Save','Save and Close'

Answer (score 2):

The best method of disabling the Save and Save & Close is to remove the 'Update' privilege from the user - CRM will automatically disable these buttons for you.

If you need to do this based on some record based condition, you can use the Ribbon Workbench for Dynamics CRM:

1) Create a solution including the entity that you wish to change (or add the application ribbon to make the change on all ribbons)

2) Add a webresource containing any javascript functions you may need to use

3) Load the solution into the Ribbon Workbench

4) Change to the 'Form' ribbon

5) Select the 'Save' button and right click->'Customise Command'

6) Find the command in the 'Solution elements' and change the enable rules.

7) If you don't need to customise any of the core enable/display rules, you can change the 'IsCore' property to True so that it uses the base definition.

If you need any support with this - you can use http://ribbonworkbench.uservoice.com/ 'Contact Us'.

Scott

Answer (score 1):

This is example for hidding 'Insert template' ribbon button on Email entity.
Just modify this to disable your necessary button.

```
var buttonID = "email|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.email.ApplyTemplate-Large"; // id of ribbon button
var btn = window.top.document.getElementById(buttonID);
if(btn)
{
   btn.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: There are supported ways of doing this without resorting to modifying the DOM.

Comment: i tried for the above code with the following changes , but its not working, i want to disable the system button like 'Save'.
var buttonID="fmc_vehicle|NoRelationship|Form|Mscrm.Form.fmc_vehicle.Save-Large";
          var btn = window.top.document.getElementById(buttonID);

         // alert( btn );
          if(btn)
              {
               btn.disabled = false;
              }

Comment: Hi! I've just tried your code on my custom entity and it's work. Just put btn.disabled = true  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [CRM 2011 Visual Ribbon Editor](http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/).
The easiest way, I think, If you use CRM On-Premises.

If not try [Ribbon Workbench for Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx)

Comment: I don't think either of those tools can *disable* a system ribbon control; only hide them.

Comment: Yes, you're right.
You can only hide it.